# Perl regex to catch spam pattern "ÿþ<"?

Tags: regex, perl

My forum is getting spammed by some bot that is including the character "ÿþ<" (when decoded using iso-8859-1) in its posts.  No links, just random text that includes these characters.  here's an example:

> AZ couple reduce works thing our They you ÿþ< service to busy, one get on Mens acquire ÿþ< evaluation simply buy to data information theyd duration ÿþ< they about she re-engagement results. business had of ÿþ< subscriber the run ensure data street security Phoenix

It appears to be the bytes FF and FE before the less-than.

**I want to develop a Perl regex to catch these characters, but I don't quite know how to do that.  Can anyone advise on the regex?**  What purpose might they be posting this for?  I know xruner probes sites for vulnerabilities, but this doesn't resemble any forum link shortcut I've ever seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

U+FEFF becomes FF FE when encoded using UTF-16le.

At the start of a text, U+FEFF is the UTF-16le BOM. Elsewhere, it's a zero-width non-breaking space (which is to say an invisible, function-less character).

I can think of two offensive uses. Both involve situations where HTML is checked for malicious content by one program before being used by another.

- If the checker is fooled to switching to UTF-16le when it encounters `FF FE` (because it incorrectly believes it to be a BOM), the following `<` would appear as something other than `<` to it, thus bypassing checks for `<`. This would allow `\xFF\xFE<script>...</script>` (for example) to bypass the checks for those tags.
- The checker could correctly determine that `<\x{FEFF}script` (decoded from UTF-16le) is not an HTML element and allow `<\x{FEFF}script>...</script>` through to a buggy browser that filters out all instances of U+FEFF. This browser would see `<script>...</script>` where there isn't one.

---

You probably plan on removing the characters, but that's a bad idea. Removing would introduce the second security problem I mentioned above. Instead, you should leave them be or change them to [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

```
s/[\xFE\xFF]/\x{FFFD}/g
```

Comment: So they were probing for a way to get a backdoor angle bracket in.  I think I can safely conclude if the body etc. of the post includes that character, the post is spam.  So I just redirect them to the FBI's cybercrimes page.  I'm sure that accomplishes nothing, but it makes me smile.

Comment: Yeah, I find it very to believe FF FE could be inserted by accident. (I can imagine the UTF-8 encoding of the BOM being inserted by accident in template-generated emails, but very very rarely.)

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should work for a multibyte character:

```
$string =~ m/\x{00FF}/;
```

Comment: Thanks Mauritz - I was using Cloudflare for my CDN, and they also block malicious users.  As soon as I turned it off for testing, these posts started flooding in.  I wonder what vulnerability they were exploiting....

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{
    use bytes;
    /\xff\xfe\x3c/ and print "found\n" while <>;
}
```

See [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16):

> UTF-16 (LE)   FF FE   255 254     ÿþ

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx will match those multibyte characters: `\xFF\xFE<`